# Can DNS-over-HTTPS be broken by reverse DNS lookups?

Tags: tls, http, dns

If anyone can see the receiver IP address in a HTTPS request, what will stop ISPs from analysing the packet, reverse DNS lookup the IP and block the access to the domain the client is trying to reach. Is this possible and if yes how much would it slow down traffic?

This is a followup question to [Will HTTPS expose the IP address of the receiver?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220432/will-https-expose-the-ip-address-of-the-receiver)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Do you mean that the ISP can block access to the DNS server or that the ISP can block access to the domain the client is ultimately trying to reach (i.e. the domain the DNS lookup is done for)?

Comment: That the ISP can block the access to the domain the client is trying to reach

Comment: Am I right then you are then in essence you just ask if the ISP can block just by looking at HTTPS (target IP, SNI) even if he could not block by DNS any longer?

Comment: Yes, by looking at the target IP, making a reverse DNS lookup and check if that domain has to be blocked.

Comment: Then I've marked it correctly as a duplicate since this idea is answered already.